# Creating multiple instances of a class. Most idiomatic?

Tags: ruby

If we think about a grocery store that has a set of stock.
I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to do this?

Firstly I have a lovely Shelves class:

```
# The Shelves class holds the items in the market
class Shelves
  attr_reader :item_price

  def initialize(item_name, item_price, item_promo_group, item_quantity)
    @item_name = item_name
    @item_price = item_price
    @item_promogroup = item_promo_group
    @item_quantity = item_quantity
  end
end
```

My intention is to call Market.new and create an initial set of stock.
Currently I am instantiating multiple instances of Shelves like so:

```
class Market
  attr_reader :initial_stock

  def initialize
    @initial_stock = [Shelves.new('item1',  1.00, 'A', 10),
                      Shelves.new('item2',  1.50, 'B',  9),
                      Shelves.new('item3',  2.00, 'C',  8),
                      Shelves.new('item4',  2.50, 'A',  7),
                      Shelves.new('item5',  3.00, 'B',  6),
                      Shelves.new('item6',  4.50, 'C',  5),
                      Shelves.new('item7',  5.00, 'A',  4),
                      Shelves.new('item8',  1.00, 'B',  3),
                      Shelves.new('item9',  1.50, 'C',  2),
                      Shelves.new('item10', 2.00, 'A',  1)]
  end
end
```

It's in an array because ... well mostly I'm using it to sum all the prices to get a total stock price. I thought of doing it another way like using instance variables but that also feels too lengthy i.e something like:

```
@apple = Shelves.new('apple',  1.00, 'A', 10)
@banana = Shelves.new('banana',  1.00, 'A', 10)
@pear = Shelves.new('pear',  1.00, 'A', 10)
```

Basically I'm asking, what is the most idiomatic way to do something similar to the above?

Comment: You're trying to model something like **a *Market* has many *Items* through *Shelves***. This type of relational modeling is very common in normalized databases, and relatively easy to do in Rails. You may want to look at [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for a Rails-centric approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

Modeling business domain objects isn't trivial. For robust real-world inventory management, you'll probably want a real database rather than "plain old Ruby objects" (POROs) to manage [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations and data normalization, but you can certainly *model* your problem domain using some fairly basic POROs like [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html) and [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Struct.html).

### Domain Modeling Example and Sample Usage

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it seems like the problem is more about how to properly model the domain than anything else. You really need a fully normalized database with a schema that describes the items in your inventory (and likely each item's location data such as aisles and shelves) rather than complex Ruby objects.

That said, if you're just trying to find a way to represent your current data set in plain Ruby, you might consider the following approach:

```
require 'singleton'

class Inventory
  include Singleton
  attr_accessor :items

  def initialize
    @items = []
  end
end

class Item < Struct.new(:name, :price, :quantity, :promo_group)        
end

inventory = Inventory.instance

inventory.items.append(
  Item.new('apple',  0.99, 5, 'A'),
  Item.new('orange', 1.50, 7, 'B'),
)
```

Basically, the idea is to create a [singleton](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) Inventory object that contains an array of Item objects. Each Item object is a [Struct](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Struct.html) that contains whatever data you may need. You manipulate the inventory through the Inventory#items getter and setter methods, or reference the attributes of a single Item in the inventory through the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html)-like behavior of its Struct. For example:

```
inventory.items
#=> [#<struct Item name="apple", price=0.99, quantity=5, promo_group="A">, #<struct Item name="orange", price=1.5, quantity=7, promo_group="B">]

inventory.items.map &:name
#=> ["apple", "orange"]

inventory.items.select { _1.promo_group == ?A }
#=> [#<struct Item name="apple", price=0.99, quantity=5, promo_group="A">]

inventory.items.filter { _1.name == 'apple' }.count
#=> 1

inventory.items.filter { _1.name == 'apple' }.map &:to_h
#=> [{:name=>"apple", :price=>0.99, :quantity=>5, :promo_group=>"A"}]
```

This solves for the question you asked, but you'll have to build your own methods for basic operations like searching, adding, deleting, or updating specific inventory items. A real database with [object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (e.g. an ORM interface like [ActiveRecord](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), or similar on top of a SQL or NoSQL database) is really a better solution for a real-world application.

Comment: Thanks very much for such a detailed answer. This makes a lot of sense to me. I have a small question. Is the use of singleton to ensure that there is only one copy of the Inventory class in existence? For example if I omitted including the concept of singleton and invoking the class as an instance, in theory would I be fine providing I didn't create multiple instances of the Inventory class?

Comment: @OctopusNZ Yes. You could manually use a single instance of the Inventory class, or use class variables instead of an instance variable to hold your items array. Using Singleton is a design choice that offers some benefits, but there are certainly other ways to solve for maintaining a singular inventory data structure.